# how to use grub-uboot

Tags: linux, grub2, arm

On an ARM-based device, I'd like to chain-load uboot->GRUB->Linux

I see there is a [Debian package](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/grub-uboot) that seems to be made for that, however I can't find no documentation whatsoever how to use it (ie. how it should be installed).

Any hints for some information to get started?

Answer (score -1):

Did not try that myself.
Did not have the need yet.
But some hints:

1. I saw [this page](https://wiki.linaro.org/LEG/ServerArchitecture/GRUBonUBOOT) in Linaro
2. You just need to try (and work on SD card if possible so you can revert in case it fails!)
3. Both UBOOT and Grub are fully free software, so you can see the code. See the source label on Debian package, or use 'apt source grub2' inside a Debian system, remember that each Debian source package can produce several binary packages, so do not get confused by not getting the 'same' package.

Comment: The source code is available is a pretty useless answer. The source code does not explain how to, for example, prepare an SD card to be "ubooted" and then chain-load grub.